# C# - How to check if first period of time is during second period of time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

```
//first period start
DateTime FirstStart = new DateTime(2021,10,20);
DateTime FirstStop = new DateTime(2021,10,22);
//first period ends
```

```
//second period start
DateTime SecondStart = new DateTime(2021,10,21);
DateTime SecondStop = new DateTime(2021,10,23);
//second period stop
```

I need to check if can add Second period, but condition is that it can't be during first period.

```
public bool IsAvailable(Vechile vechile, DateTime RentFrom, DateTime RentTo)
{
     if (vechile.Calendar.Any(x => (x.To >= RentFrom) && (x.From <= RentTo)))
     {
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.

please also read [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `bool overlaps = (FirstStop >= SecondStart) && (FirstStart <= SecondEnd);`

Comment: Is this really an EF question or just how do I compare 2 date ranges for overlap?  because if you want to integrate with EF, you want to create a DateRange/Period class like @harald, but you want to inherit from ValueObject.  As well as make that value object immutable. You also need to map your DateRange class in your entity using OwnsOne / Owned syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be using these time periods for several purposes, my advice would be to create a class for it, with the proper methods.

```
class Period // TODO invent proper name. Era?
{
    public DateTime Start {get; set;}
    public Datetime End {get; set;}

    public TimeSpan Length => this.Stop - this.Start;

    public bool IsIn (DateTime date)
    {
        return this.Start <= date && this.End >= date;
    }

    public bool OverLaps (Period period)
    {
        return period.Start < this.End && period.End > this.Start;
    }
}
```

By making it a class, it will be asier to understand what happens. It will be easier to reuse the Period for other purposes, because as soon as you have a Period, you will have all methods needed for this.

You will als be prepared for future changes. For instance, if you want to change the Period into a Start and a Length instead of Start and End, changes will be minimal, especially for users of your class.

If you are missing a method, for instance if you want to shorten or lengthen a Period, or unite two Periods, changes will only be in this class.

Period A overlaps Period B if it is not completely after B and not completely before B, so part of it should be before Period B ends, AND part of it should be after period starts.

Consider to add checks that Start <= End. Maybe it is a good idea to make the class immutable. Can it be that you will also need methods to combine and subtract Periods?